# AngularJS - pass filter into view template from controller

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS filters are used in view templates using this syntax:

```
{{ expression | filter }}
```

Expression can be a model defined in the controller:

```
$scope.expression = 45
```

How can I pass the built-in filter in the variable? This expression doesn't work:

```
$scope.filter = 'currency'
```

**Edit:** I am now using a slightly modified function from the answer.

Controller:

```
$scope.expression = 45;
$scope.filter = 'currency';

$scope.filterFn = function (value, filterName, filterArgs) {
    if (filterName)
        return $filter(filterName)(value, filterArgs);
    return value;
}
```

View:

```
{{filterFn(expression, filter, args)}}
```

Comment: dynamically you can't give filter name instead you have to declare in view ex <span>{{amount | currency}}</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of applying the filter in the view you could rather apply it directly in your controller like this:

```
function YourController ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.yourFilteredVar = $filter('currency')(45);
}
```

Alternativly you could save the filter function as a property of $scope and use it in the view:

```
function YourController ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.filterFn = $filter('currency')
    $scope.yourVar =45;
}
```

And the View:

```
<span>My Var: {{filterFn(yourVar)}}</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, if you want dynamic filter names, is creation of filter that would be a wrapper for others:

```
app.filter('filterWrapper', function ($filter) {
    return function () {
        var input = arguments[0],
            name = arguments[1],
            args = [].slice.call(arguments, 2); //dirty hack, arguments are not Array
        return $filter(name)(input, args);
    }
})
```

In view use as: `{{greeting | filterWrapper:filterName }}`.

Checkout fiddle for full example http://jsfiddle.net/Y9g4q/11/.